# Angular - How to format Material Datepicker before submit

Tags: angular

In my Angular-12, I am using Material Datepicker. I have already imported it in the module.

Now in the component I have:

```
import * as _moment from 'moment';
import { Moment } from 'moment';

const moment = _moment;

onSubmit() {
const formUserData = this.userInfoForm.getRawValue();

  const data = {
    dateEstablished: formCompanyData.dateEstablished,
    firstName: formUserData.firstName,
    lastName: formUserData.lastName,
    otherName: formUserData.otherName,
  };
}
```

I tried to use:

> let dateEstablished: Moment = formCompanyData.dateEstablished;

But got this error:

> ',' is expected

How do I format dateEstablished before submitting it. That is, in onSubmit() ?

Thanks

> 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.format()` to format `Moment` object to `string`.

### Solution

> .component.ts

```js
onSubmit() {
    const formUserData = this.userInfoForm.getRawValue();
    const formCompanyData = this.companyInfoForm.getRawValue();

    let dateEstablished: Moment = formCompanyData.dateEstablished;

    const data = {
      dateEstablished: dateEstablished.format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
      firstName: formUserData.firstName,
      lastName: formUserData.lastName,
      otherName: formUserData.otherName
    };
}
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7v7az5?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

---

### Reference

[Format Dates](https://momentjs.com/)